# Problem about integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal R$ be a $\sigma$-algebra in a nonempty set $X$, let $\mu$ be a positive measure on $\mathcal R$, let $f:X\to \mathbb C$ be measurable relative to $\mathcal R$，and $f\in L^1(\mu)$. 
Let $\mathcal R^\prime$ be a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$, $\mathcal R^\prime\subset \mathcal R$, suppose $f$ is also measurable relative to $\mathcal R^\prime$。

Is
               $$\int_Xf\,\mathrm{d} \mu=\int_X f \,\mathrm{d} (\mu|_{\mathcal R^\prime})$$
true？

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

First prove it for characteristic functions $1_A$ where $A\in\mathcal R'$. This is obvious: $\mu(A)=(\mu|_{\mathcal R'})(A)$.

Then use linearity of integrals to prove it for (step)functions that are measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal R'$ and take a finite number of values.

Finally for every $f$ measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal R'$ with we can construct a sequence $t_n$ of these stepfunctions such that $t_n\rightarrow f$ and if $\int f$ is welldefined also with $\int t_n\rightarrow \int f$.